# Add or replace a parameter in the query string

Tags: python, django

It seems there's no way to capture the whole query string in Django, doesn't it? I've only the solutions for capturing individual parameters.

So how can I check whether the query string exists

I want to check whether the query string itself exists (any parameters after "?"), if it does then either replace or add the parameters "param1" to it. How can I do that? For example:

```
  localhost:8000 -> localhost:8000/?param1=a
  localhost:8000/?param1=1 -> localhost:8000/?param1=bb
  localhost:8000/?param1=1&param2=fdfd -> localhost:8000/?param1=333&param2=fdfd

  localhost:8000/?param2=fdfd -> localhost:8000/?param1=1&param2=fdfd
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`request.GET` is is the query string, and it conforms to the dictionary interface. As with all Python containers, an empty dict is False in a boolean context. So you can check if it's empty by just doing `if request.GET`.

However, in your examples it seems you're always replacing param1 anyway, do there is no need to check it first: just set the value: `request.GET['param1'] = 'whatever'`.

Comment: `request.GET` is immutable by default. You can do `request.GET = request.GET.copy()` to circumvent this.

Comment: How can I convert request.GET to a query string?

Comment: Look Here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META.  There is a key called QUERY_STRING which should return everything after the ?